# Why this button in the footer modal doesn't work?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in a bootstrap 4.0 modal, the modal has a header, body, and footer, and I decide to use the `for="my-form-id"` thing for the button outside the form ... but ... doesn't work and I don't know what I'm missing.

Things what I'm tried (The code are only a short example):

- The `for="my-form-id"` thing

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">



      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form blahblah id="my-form-id" >
           ... things in form ...
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button for="my-form-id" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Doesn't work and I tried to expanse the code inside the form

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

<form blahblah>

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

           ... things in form ...

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
      </div>

</form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The js thing and nope
- Cry a lot inside for a basic bug

I can share the codepen with all styles and js in a snippet

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="dark" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="v-alex" data-slug-hash="BXpEgp" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Quote Modal ... WHY THE FOOTER BUTTON DOESNT WORK?!">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/v-alex/pen/BXpEgp/">
  Quote Modal ... WHY THE FOOTER BUTTON DOESNT WORK?!</a> by Alex (<a href="https://codepen.io/v-alex">@v-alex</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not just wrap the entire `.modal-dialog` in your `<form>`? It won't change your layout anyway.

Comment: Your suggestion works for me and I found my mistake too: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" for="submit-form" >Send message</button>` The double definition of `type="button"` and `type="submit"` :) Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the form id in the button (i.e. *form="my-form-id"*)?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" form="my-form-id">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't work in IE and doesn't work well :/